# socket programming

Tags: silverlight

i have server has ip and three ports , and has more sender (each sender has ip) to this server , and one reciever (has its ip).  if sernder A and sender B send to server , if i want the receiver receive the data only sent from sender A (how do that by using socket programming in silverlight). i use ( AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp ). plz help me

new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

Comment: Why does sender B connect if what it sends needs not to be received ?

Comment: I would also suggest putting more information about what you have tried some socket code and where it is apparently failing

Answer (score 0):

Your message is very confusing based on punctuation, lack of Capital letters and spelling problems. But anyway.

You can't prevent on sockets level connection from specific client that you have to know IP of which or have kind of handshake after connection is established to understand which client it is.

You can do block connections from specific IP's using firewall hardware / software.

In same time, I believe it is just software task you trying to do.
So you will have some kind of identification after connecting.
Lets say server is Bound, awaiting for connections, and once they are accepted, you get new client Socket that wont be authorized before it will go through some messages exchange that will do authentication connection. If that is not done by some time, server may drop connection.

This looks like very basic task and questions you are trying to go through, I would recommend to read some basics about sockets programming.